# A group specified by Generators and Relations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, semigroups

I'm confused with some terms in several definitions.
Is an alphabet of a free group the same thing as a generator set of any group?
If it is right, then by a given alphabet (set of generators) can be generated infinite words.Thus we can't present a group uniquely by only set of generators. But I couldn't understand how the relations system solve this problem, how we can present a group with these two objects?

Answer (score 1):

What you said, strictly speaking, isn't true-for example, if our generating set has cardinality one, the resulting free group is isomorphic to the integers.

If you introduce the relator $x^n$ (that is take the quotient of the free group on one letter $x$ modulo the subgroup generated by all words made from powers of $x^n$) in the free group $F(\{x\})$, this gives you the cyclic group of order $n$. Often this relator is presented as the relation $x^n = 1$ (taking the quotient "identifies" the identity and $x^n$).

It gets more interesting if your generating set has two elements (as many more relators/relations are possible). The free group on two letters is *very* complicated, as it contains subgroups isomorphic to free groups on any finite set of letters.

If you have a relation $ba = a^kb^m$, this allows you to "always put the $a$'s first". If you also have relations like $a^r = b^s = 1$, you know your quotient of the free group is *finite*.

For example, we can realize $S_3$ (up to isomorphism) as $F(\{x,y\})/N$, where $N$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $F(\{x,y\})$ containing $\{x^3,y^2,yxyx\}$, which translates to:

$S_3 \cong \langle x,y: x^3 = y^2 = 1, yx = x^2y\rangle$

The relation $yx = x^2y$ allows us to write any word in $S_3$ as $x^jy^k$, and we only have 3 choices for $j$ and 2 choices for $k$, giving six potential elements (which turn out to be all distinct).